# Cipher AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding cant decrypt after application reinitialization

Tags: java, encryption, aes, password-encryption

I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt some texts using Cipher with the "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding" algorithm but if I restart the application the text that was encrypt can't be decrypted.
I'm encrypting the text, transforming the encrypted bytes in base64 text, storing it and retrieving it when necessary, so transforming the base64 text in bytes and trying to decrypt to take the original text.

The code I'm using is:

```
private static SecretKey getKeyFromPassword(String password, String salt)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {

    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt.getBytes(UTF_8),
            65536, 256);
    SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(spec)
            .getEncoded(), "AES");
    return secret;
}


private static IvParameterSpec generateIv() {
    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    new SecureRandom().nextBytes(iv);
    return new IvParameterSpec(iv);
}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
        // string for test
        String teste = "teste teste teste teste";

        //getting start with Cipher
        SecretKey secretKey = getKeyFromPassword("pass", "salt");
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = generateIv();
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        //encrypting
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivParameterSpec);
        byte[] cipherText = new byte[0];
        cipherText = cipher.doFinal(teste.getBytes(UTF_8));

        // encrypt to base64 text
        String criptado = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText);
        

        //decripting
        byte[] plainText = new byte[0];
        byte[] rawText = Base64.getDecoder().decode(criptado);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivParameterSpec);
        plainText = cipher.doFinal(rawText);
        String decriptado = new String(plainText);
```

The problem is something with the size of the bit key? Like in this topic: [java AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING in php (AES-256-CBC) resulting different result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53038866/java-aes-cbc-pkcs5padding-in-php-aes-256-cbc-resulting-different-result)

I took this guide to the code: baeldung.com/java-aes-encryption-decryption

Comment: Are you storing IV somewhere? Seems like you only store it in memory so when the app restarts, a new IV is generated and decryption fails. You need to store the IV along with encrypted data.

Comment: Hmmm Thx! Even the IV being the same every time in the construction ? I will try it and do some search about that

Comment: @Tasos P.: using the same IV for IV reduces the security to "near null" so please do not "offer" such a solution. The problem is exact what you described in your first comment - for decryption you need to use the the same IV for decryption that was used on encryption. That will work when you run both in a row but not after a restart. OP: store the IV in Base64 encoding along with the ciphertext (do not need to be secured) and for decryption decode it and everything will work.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you @MichaelFehr. Greatly reduced is an understatement.

Comment: @MichaelFehr I respectfully disagree with Tasos P; near null is an **overstatement**, as you would just gain some knowledge if the initial blocks are identical. The same kind of leakage can happen if an attacker is able to create a chosen plaintext attack - which is not always the case. CBC is slightly more forgivable than e.g. CTR (and therefore GCM) mode in that sense.

Comment: The problem here is that the `Cipher` instance is reduced. This may seem a good idea, but of course it makes no sense to have them in the same method in practice. You're better off splitting the encryption / decryption routines. In that case the issue with the IV would have popped up as well.

Comment: Note that the assignment of a zero byte array makes no sense, you can remove the `= new byte[0]` and have the same code. Usually this is a leftover from an IDE including a `printStackTrace` statement, which is moronic in itself. If anything, unhandled exceptions should be the cause of a `RuntimeException`.